# z-index issue on chrome and safari (firefox is fine)

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, z-index

I seem to have a stupid z-index issue on chrome and safari, which I can't find any solution for it.

I prepared a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j3kyvnym/1/

When Scrolling down, the Page Content should be above the header (grey bar) but below the logo.  Works as expected in Firefox, but chrome and safari doesn't apply the z-index on the logo element.

Am I missing something?
(I don't want the logo to be absolute or fixed positioned)

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
</header>

<div id="page-body">
    Page Content
</div>
```

CSS (simplified):

```
header {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    position: fixed;  
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

#page-body {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, with my knowledge on how z-index works, with the given html structure, this cannot be done unless you make the background of the header transparent. Then visually it will look like the way you want. I am not sure why FF is displaying it the way it is. Maybe there is a way and I just don't know it, I would be interested to see if there is a proper way of achieving this

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be a big deal, but apparently it is.  I think in this case Firefox handles it the right way. It's a pitty that chrome + safari doesn't do so.  As you said, I think I need to change the html structure, or find some other workaround

Comment: I believe FF is handling it the wrong way which is rare, but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logo is inside a parent, the header, and will inherit its z-index. So right now you're asking #page-body to weave in between two layers and it can't.

A solution would be to put your z-index on the header and make its background transparent:

http://jsfiddle.net/keithburgie/j3kyvnym/5/

```
header {
 padding: 20px 0;
 background: none;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;  
 z-index: 10;
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, you can place the logo outside the header element, change its position to fixed and use a negative margin to place it on top of the header:

http://jsfiddle.net/keithburgie/j3kyvnym/8/

```
<div class="container">

<header></header>

<div class="logo">Logo</div>

<div id="page-body">
    Page Content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I thought when I don't apply a z-index to the parent header, the logo will not inherit its z-index.  Firefix does it like I want it.  However, I will try to find another solution for it.  Transparent background is bad, because the content elements wouldn't be accessible (anchor tag for example) because the header is overlaying it.

Answer (score 0):

remove z-index and position from .logo and #page-body

```
.logo {
   height: 40px; line-height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    background: red;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#page-body {
      margin-top: 100px; 
   margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

[here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3kyvnym/2/)

Comment: I think the OP wants the the text to be behind the logo but above the `header`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then the content is behind the whole header


@Huangism, yes exactly

Comment: Now the content is above the header AND the logo.  I want it to be 'inbetween'. Above the header (grey bar) but below the logo.